# Restrict interface's property value to one of object's values

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I want TypeScript to throw an error if the object that is type of `IExpression` interface has a `expressions.null.property` or `expressions.video.property` value that is not one of `PROPERTIES` values.

I have this object:

```
const PROPERTIES =  {
    ANCHOR_POINT: 'anchorPoint',
    POSITION: 'position',
    X_POSITION: 'xPosition',
    Y_POSITION: 'yPosition',
    Z_POSITION: 'zPosition',
    SCALE: 'scale',
    ORIENTATION: 'orientation',
    ROTATION: 'rotation',
    X_ROTATION: 'xRotation',
    Y_ROTATION: 'yRotation',
    Z_ROTATION: 'zRotation',
    OPACITY: 'opacity',
};
```

And I want to restrict IExpression.expressions.null.property to one of PROPERTIES values.

Here's how I'm trying to make it work:

```
type NULL_OR_VIDEO = "null" | "video";

interface IExpression {
    name: string;
    targets: FILE[];
    expressions: {
        [value in NULL_OR_VIDEO]: {
            property: PROPERTIES;
            expressionText: string;
        }
    }
}
```

It's throwing errors though. I know I can probably do this by doing this:

```
interface IExpression {
    name: string;
    targets: FILE[];
    expressions: {
        [value in NULL_OR_VIDEO]: {
            property: 'rotation' | 'xRotation'| 'opacity' ...
            expressionText: string;
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

I converted the `PROPERTIES` to an enum:

```
enum PROPERTIES  {
    ANCHOR_POINT = 'anchorPoint',
    POSITION = 'position',
    X_POSITION = 'xPosition',
    Y_POSITION = 'yPosition',
    Z_POSITION = 'zPosition',
    SCALE = 'scale',
    ORIENTATION = 'orientation',
    ROTATION = 'rotation',
    X_ROTATION = 'xRotation',
    Y_ROTATION = 'yRotation',
    Z_ROTATION = 'zRotation',
    OPACITY = 'opacity',
};
```

Which now works like this:

```
interface IExpression {
    name: string;
    targets: FILE[];
    expressions: {
        [value in NULL_OR_VIDEO]?: {
            property: PROPERTIES;
            expressionText: string;
        }
    }
}
```